# Why does this delete cause a core dump?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

This code works appropriately if I don't use and then delete a pointer for the base class `Output`.  The destructor for Output is called and seems to work appropriately.  Am I missing something here?

```
// multiple inheritance
// Testing overload of muliple inheritance of pure virtual functions.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Polygon {
  protected:
    int width, height;
  public:
    Polygon (int a, int b) : width(a), height(b) {}
    ~Polygon() = default;
    virtual int area() = 0;
};

class Output {
  private:
    string* myString;

  public:
    Output() {
      myString = nullptr;
    }

    Output(const string& s) {
      myString = new string(s);
    }

    // This seems to work, but ther core dump happens right afterwards.
    ~Output() {
      cout << "delete called with: " << myString << '\n';
      if (myString != nullptr)
        delete myString;
    }
    virtual int area() = 0;
    void print () {
      cout << *myString << this->area() << '\n';
    }
};



class Rectangle: public Polygon, public Output {
  public:
    Rectangle (int a, int b) : Polygon(a,b), Output{"A Rectangle's area is: "} {}
    int area () {
     return width*height;
   }
};

class Triangle: public Polygon, public Output  {
  public:
    Triangle (int a, int b) : Polygon{a,b}, Output{"A Triangle's area is: "} {}
    int area ()
      { return width*height/2; }
};

int main () {
  Output * ptr1 = new Rectangle(4,5);
  Output * ptr2 = new Triangle(4,5);

  ptr1->print();
  ptr2->print();

  // Causes core dump.  
  delete ptr1;
  delete ptr2;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several major issues with this code:

First, you should not use multiple inheritance for this.  It is completely unnecessary and will lead to very difficult to track down bugs.

Second, you do not need to test for `nullptr` before deleting a pointer - it is redundant as `delete` already does that.

Third, neither of your base classes has a virtual destructor. (your current error)

Forth, you are violating the [Rule of 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) in your `Output` class (and likely will need to use it in all of them).

Fifth, assuming `string` means `std::string`.  There is no reason for it to be a `string*` - just use `std::string` and avoid having to allocate and deallocate it.

I didn't fix your design issues, but your memory access and polymorphic issues are fixed [here](http://ideone.com/Bug1v5).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Polygon 
{
  protected:
    int width, height;
  public:
    Polygon (int a, int b) : width(a), height(b) {}
    virtual ~Polygon() { } // needed!
    virtual int area() = 0;
};

class Output 
{
  private:
    std::string myString; // no need to be a pointer

  public:
    Output() {    }

    Output(const string& s) : myString(s) {   }

    virtual ~Output() {    } // also needed!
    virtual int area() = 0;
    void print () {
      cout << myString << this->area() << '\n';
    }
};



class Rectangle: public Polygon, public Output 
{
  public:
    Rectangle (int a, int b) : Polygon(a,b), Output{"A Rectangle's area is: "} {}
    int area () {
     return width*height;
   }
};

class Triangle: public Polygon, public Output  
{
  public:
    Triangle (int a, int b) : Polygon{a,b}, Output{"A Triangle's area is: "} {}
    int area ()
      { return width*height/2; }
};

int main () 
{
  Output * ptr1 = new Rectangle(4,5);
  Output * ptr2 = new Triangle(4,5);

  ptr1->print();
  ptr2->print();

  // Causes core dump.  
  delete ptr1;
  delete ptr2;

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT:  An example of a better way to implement the desired program can be found [here](http://ideone.com/MPo4Ql).

Comment: Making his destructors virtual was enough to fix the original problem in my debugger but all your points are very valid and should be heeded.

Comment: This is really a modified example from cplusplus.com, I don't think I would go about it this way for the inheritance.  I noticed in your code you removed the `delete myString`, this doesn't result in a memory leak?  The actual error was caused by the lack of virtual destructors in the base class, the allocation of std::string worked correctly.

Comment: @MrMowgli It will not cause a memory leak because it also does not allocate a `string` dynamically.  And while cplusplus.com has some decent references for the standard library, many of the examples it gives are nowhere close to being decent code.  And while some of the other points may not have been hitting you *yet* (e.g. the Rule of 3 violation with dynamic memory), it would as soon as you tried to do something like `Output obj1 = *obj2`;

Comment: @MrMowgli I've added some clarification to my answer.

Comment: @ZacHowland, interesting examples - I like that you also showed examples of the  Rule of 3 and the overload of the << operator.

Comment: @ZacHowland: For posterity could you inline the first example in your response?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Output` and `Polygon` class destructors should be `virtual` also:

```
class Output {
  private:
    std::string* myString;

  public:
        // ...

    virtual ~Output() { 
 // ^^^^^^^
    }
};
```

**Also note:** Instead of using a `std::string*` pointer, you can simply use a `std::string myString;` member:

```
  private:
    std::string myString;
```

and leave behind bothering around with getting `new string()` and `delete myString;` right for any cases.

Comment: But would a virtual destructor for Output also call OUtput's destructor by default?

Comment: Ah I see, it still gets called appropriately.  Thanks!